# GNU "parallel" how to achieve tee behaviour

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, tee

Is it possible to use gnu-parallel to run multiple commands which all read from stdin?

For example:

```sh
echo 'hello world' | parallel --keep-order --tagstring 'Part {=$_=uc($_)=}:' --pipe "cat" ::: {a,b}
```

I would like to see:

```
Part A: hello world
Part B: hello world
```

as output. However, I only see:

```
Part A: hello world
```

I've also tried:

```
echo 'hello world' | parallel --keep-order --tagstring 'Part {=$_=uc($_)=}:' --pipe --fifo 'cat < {}' ::: {a,b}
```

but the output is also wrong

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like gnu parallel actually comes with a `--tee` option (lol).

> Pipe all data to all jobs.

The solution is fairly simple:

```
echo 'hello world' | parallel --keep-order --tagstring 'Part {=$_=uc($_)=}:' --pipe --tee "cat" ::: {a,b}
```

Output:

```
Part A: hello world
Part B: hello world
```

As expected